# Split dataframe by equal distribution of unique values ( values_counts ) of a categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, split

I have a dataframe of 1000 rows with a string column named "color", the distribution (frequency) of value_counts is:

- Red 10%
- Green 5%
- Red 20%
- Yellow 10%
- White 35%
- Black 20%

I want to create a sample of 100 rows that have an equal distribution if value_counts of column "color", meaning:

- Red 10%
- Green 5%
- Red 20%
- Yellow 10%
- White 35%
- Black 20%

How to achieve this?

Comment: You have `Red` twice in your data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# create original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
'color': ['red']*100 + ['green']*50 + ['yellow']*200 + ['white']*350 + ['black']*200
})

# get value counts of the original dataframe
value_counts = df['color'].value_counts()

# calculate the number of rows for each color in the sample
n = 100
sample_value_counts = {color: round(n * value_counts[color] / len(df)) for color in value_counts.index}

# create empty sample dataframe
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['color'])

# add rows to the sample dataframe
for color, count in sample_value_counts.items():
sample_df = pd.concat([sample_df, df[df['color'] == color].sample(n=count)])

# reset the index of the sample dataframe
sample_df = sample_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define the original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "color": ["Red"]*100 + ["Green"]*50 + ["Red"]*200 + ["Yellow"]*100 + ["White"]*350 + ["Black"]*200
})

# Define the desired frequency distribution
desired_dist = {
    "Red": 0.1,
    "Green": 0.05,
    "Yellow": 0.1,
    "White": 0.35,
    "Black": 0.2
}

# Calculate the number of samples to take for each color
num_samples = int(100 / len(desired_dist))
color_counts = df["color"].value_counts(normalize=True)
sample_sizes = {}
for color in desired_dist.keys():
    sample_sizes[color] = int(num_samples * color_counts[color] / desired_dist[color])
    
# Take a random sample of the appropriate size for each color
sampled_df = pd.DataFrame()
for color, size in sample_sizes.items():
    color_rows = df[df["color"] == color]
    sampled_group = color_rows.sample(n=size, replace=False)
    sampled_df = pd.concat([sampled_df, sampled_group])
    
# Shuffle the final sampled dataframe
sampled_df = sampled_df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

# Check the resulting distribution of the sampled dataframe
sampled_df["color"].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Comment: Did you actually try this code? It has several problems...

Comment: Code runs now but the value counts do not match the desired distribution